# Using .htaccess I want to redirect based on http_referer all subdomains EXCEPT two specific subdomains

Tags: regex, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, regex-negation, http-referer

Using .htaccess I am struggling to compose the correct regex to redirect based on http_referer all subdomains EXCEPT two.

Lets say I had

```
one.refered.com
two.refered.com
```

that I did not want to redirect but `example.refered.com` or `[any other subdomain but one or two].refered.com`.

To get them I could use

```
RewriteCond %{http_referer} ^http://([^.]+.)*(refered).com
RewriteRule ^$ yoursite.html [R=302,L]
```

but I am struggling with the exclusion part.

Answer (score 1):

Try this rule:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} ^http://(.+\.)*refered\.com
RewriteCond %1 !^(one|two)\.$
RewriteRule ^$ yoursite.html [R=302,L]
```

- In first condition we capture subdomain name
- In second condition we check if captured subdomain name is not equal `one.` or `two.`

If both conditions met (the default "relation" between conditions is logical **AND**), then we proceed with rewriting/redirecting.

Test data:

```
http://meow.refered.com/hello.php     = redirect
http://one.refered.com/hello.php      = ignore
http://one.two.refered.com/hello.php  = redirect
```

Answer (score 0):

This is super tricky and I wouldn't recommend doing this unless you have to feed it to another tool (which apparently you do).

```
http://(?!one|two)(\w+\.)+(?<!one|two)referred\.com
```

This says:

Find "http://" as long at isn't followed by "one" or "two"

find any number of subdomains (\w.)+

then find "referred.com" as long as it isn't preceded by "one" or two"

```
http://one.referred.com                  * no match
http://two.referred.com                  * no match
http://blah.referred.com                 * matches
http://blah.one.blah.referred.com        * matches
http://two.blah.referred.com             * no match
```